# If passing as base type reference, does the derived type deconstruct?

Tags: c++, inheritance, pass-by-reference, destructor

I have a Base class, that is considered read-only, and in it's virtual desructor it does nothing.
Now I derive that Base class into a Derived class, which is writable, and in it's destructor, it deletes the Base member:

```
class Base
{
    virtual ~Base() {}
    void* Data;
}
class Derive : public virtual Base
{
    virtual ~Derive() { delete Data; }
}
```

Ignoring the syntactically incorrect code above, if I were to pass a Derive instance into a Function that takes the Base class as a reference:

```
void Function(const Base& base)
{
   ...
}

...
Derive der = Derive();
...
Function(der);
```

Would the Derived destructor be called at the end of the Function scope?  I had trouble looking for the right keywords to find an answer, so my apologies if it's been asked before.  I am assuming the C++ treats references for what typw they are and not for type they could be, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it wouldn't, because the object doesn't go out of scope. It goes out of scope, and is automatically destroyed after the call to `Function`.

```
{
  Derive der = Derive();
  //...
  Function(der);
  //...
  //der still alive here
} //der is destroyed here, all destructors are called correctly
```

If you were to pass the parameter **by value** instead of by reference:

```
void Function(Base base)
{
   ...
}
```

the object would be **sliced**. The copy created inside `Function` is an object of type `Base` (not `Derive`) so only the `Base` destructor would be called when the function exits.

Comment: you probably mean `Derive der;` everything else goes with `new/delete` and no automatical deletion?

Comment: @duedl0r no, what I wrote is completely correct. It does copy initialization from a temporary.

Comment: I should have known this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Would the Derived destructor be called at the end of the Function scope?

No. The Derived destructor is called when the object itself rather than a reference to it goes out of scope. The reference isn't the object. It's just an alias. Alternatively, think of references as pointers that can't be null, can't be reassigned, and use `.` to access members rather than `->`. Other than that, they're just pointers. When you pass a pointer to a function, just because the pointer goes out of scope at function end doesn't mean the pointed-to object goes out of scope. The same applies with references.

You're design is a bit funky. Some questions:

- What's with that `void*` data member in class `Base`?
- Why a `void*` pointer? That smacks of C rather than C++.
- Does any member function in class `Base` use that data member?

  - If not, why is that data member a part of the class?
- That `~Derive()` deletes this rather than `~Base()` is more than a bit suspect. What's the rationale behind this design?